# Microsoft Access style reports

Tags: 2013, list-view, data-view-web-part, reports

Is there a way to build MS Access style reports with SharePoint list data without using Access?

I'm currently able to query a list by making a REST call and dynamicly building an HTML table with the data. With MS Access there is a report builder that connects to a data source and let's you build custom reports. OOTB only lets you create custom views which puts every record on one line. I need to be able to put multiple fields of a record across multiple rows. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few OOTB reporting solutions for SharePoint. There are a variety of Web Parts available, current favourite is Power BI https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-reports for more conventional reporting [SSRS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/report-data-ssrs) is very much like an Access report. SharePoint reporting can be a complex area and generally requires a reporting server.